# Convert an integer to a fixed-length character array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, char, int

I have an integer `x` that contains a 1-4 digit number. How can I convert it to a 4-character array of the digits (padded with zeroes if necessary)? That is, if `x` is `4`, I want character array `y` to contain `0004`

Comment: Takes about 10 lines of code at most to do this homework assignment.  Good luck to you!

Comment: Wow @MichaelMrozek, that was a pretty radical edit (and while it makes the question more clear, I thought S.O. frowned on radical edits like that).

Comment: @MichaelDautermann: No, any edit that makes the question more clear or more useful is encouraged.

Comment: @CodyGray: Within reason. If the question is more clear, but no longer means the same thing, then that's bad. So you have to be reasonably confident that you've understood the poster's intent.

Comment: @ruakh: Sure, I suppose. Unless the question is dangerously bordering on being closed, in which case, any edits to salvage the question are encouraged (if possible). This reflects the larger goal of this site as a repository of useful, expert-level information, not just something for people to get their questions answered. Your ability to get a good answer ties in directly with your ability to ask a good question. If you fail to ask a good question, and someone else turns your question *into* a good question that doesn't precisely mirror your intent, well then that's good for the site, sorry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
// Assume x is in the correct range (0 <= x <= 9999)
char target[5];
sprintf(target, "%04d", x);
```

Comment: This is *probably* what the OP wants, so +1, but it's not actually what the OP asked for. What the OP asked for is `char y[4] = {x / 1000, x / 100 % 10, x / 10 % 10, x % 10};`. I think it's worth explicitly noting this discrepancy, just in case.

Comment: That sort of assumption (in your first line) is going to cause a program crash sooner or later.

Comment: @James - I also don't have a 'main', so it won't even run. If I tried writing a complete program, I would have added a check, but I only aimed to answer the question. I stated the assumption so that the OP knows that my code assumes that.

Comment: @ruakh - Why is it not what the OP asked for? These are two valid answers.

Comment: @Asaf: Because the OP specified (e.g.) `{0; 0; 0; 4}`, not `{'0'; '0'; '0'; '4'}`. Though I suppose the syntax is broken in either case.

Comment: @ruakh - Oh. you're right. I don't know how I missed the difference. +1 for your comment then :)

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you are guaranteed to have only 4 elements in the vector, I think you will be able to do with with the following:

```
  char result[4];
  for(int i=0;i<4;++i)
  {
    result[3-i] = (value % 10);
    value /= 10; 
  }
```

Comment: This is the way I would do it, but I'd be using const for the array size(s) to get rid of the magical numbers.

Comment: Agreed, I was just typing up something quick and dirty.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
char y[5];
sprintf(y, "%4d", x);
```

Comment: This is definitively not C++, also it is not safe because you could overrun the buffer when written that way (if x is more than 4 digits, like 1000000). To avoid the overrun you need `snprintf()` and also make sure that buf is null terminated `buf[sizeof(buf) / sizeof(buf[0])] = '\0';`.

Answer (score 0):

What is the logical role of the number?  Normally, you'd define a 
manipulator whose name is based on the logical role, and use it.  Maybe
somthing like:

```
class serialno
{
    int myWidth;
public:
    serialno( int width ) : myWidth( width ) {}
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(
        std::ostream& stream, serialno const& manip )
    {
        stream.fill( '0' );
        stream.width( myWidth );
        return stream;
    }
};
```

You can then write:

```
std::cout << serialno( 4 ) << myNumber;
```

(A better implementation would save the formatting state of the stream,
and restore it in the destructor, called at the end of the full
expression.)

To put this into a character array, of course, you use an
`std::ostringstream` rather than `std::cout`.